# Set ticker to use setTimeout instead of setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read that `setTimeout` is less cpu resources intensive than `setInterval`. This is my main reason to switch to `setTimeout`.

This is the code of my ticker which is working perfectly fine, but I can't figure it out how make it work with `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

```
function tick() {
  $('#ticker li:first').slideUp(1000, function() {
    $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown(1000);
  });
}
setInterval(function() {
  tick()
}, 9000);
```

Comment: [setTimeout() or setInterval()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

Comment: Just replace `setInterval` by `setTimeout` if this is what you really want to do.

Comment: *"I read that setTimeout is less cpu resources intensive"*: could you include the reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout`, change this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  tick()
}, 9000);
```

to:

```
setTimeout(function repeat() {
  tick();
  setTimeout(repeat, 9000);
}, 9000);
```

However, `setTimeout` used in this repeated way will not use less resources. On the contrary, since you have to call `setTimeout` repeatedly, there is a slight extra overhead compared to your original code.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much, that's all I wanted t know, because my main point is cpu resources.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use the `setTimeout()`-function you have to call your function recursevly (with an inital call onload or whatever):

```js
function tick()
{
    $('#ticker').append('<span>tick</span>');
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
}
tick();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ticker">

</div>
```

Comment: I tried to follow your code, but it didn't work on mine, I guess I am doing something wrong when I try to emulate your line, thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ticksCount = 0;

function tick() {
  $('#ticker li:first').slideUp(1000, function() {
    $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown(1000);
  });
}

var t = setInterval(function() {
  tick()
  if (ticksCount > 10) {
    clearInterval(t);
  }

}, 1000);
```

Here is a great tutorials which can help you:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: You can handle it like above.

Comment: I thought it would be easier, I hope I can figure it out it on my code, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `setInterval` to `setTimeout` by calling `setTimeout` inside your `tick` function, passing it recursively:

```
function tick() {
  $('#ticker li:first').slideUp(1000, function() {
    $(this).appendTo($('#ticker')).slideDown(1000);
  });
  setTimeout(tick, 9000);
}
tick();
```